# is there any way to disconnect node connection from client side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodes

i have go through many pages and stack overflow questions but i didn't found my answer according to my need so i am asking here. I know there is another way to disconnect i.e, to use example like

```
socket.emit('disconnect','');  // client side call

socket.on('disconnect',function(d){    // server side code
     socket.disconnect(true); // or
     socket.close();
});
```

but i want some other way to disconnect from node server where we got same effect or functionality when we do close the browser. I mean if we disconnect the connection then in server side

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(){
     // some
});
```

this socket event should trigger.

Comment: Did you try ``socket.emit("end");`` on client side?

Comment: no, does it work ?. ok i will try now?

Comment: @AleksaArsić no it does not work.

Comment: `socket.close(); and then you have the event socket.onclose((e) => {})` firing off.

Comment: @PerDigesen socket.close() works when this called from server end. I need to close connection from client side

Comment: Have you tried calling it from the client?

Comment: @PerDigesen no i didn't. ok i will try right now. can you please explain this socket.onclose(((e)=>{}) how to use this?

Comment: @PerDigesen. Thanks i does work and socket.on('disconnect') event also triggered. Thank you. But please explain me socket.onclose((e)=>{}) how to use this one?

Comment: Its same as disconnect, so just use `socket.on('disconnect', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })`. No problem. Glad i could help.

Comment: @PerDigesen one more help. please. if i need to reconnect to node without refreshing page then how can i do this?

Comment: Just instantiate a new WebSocket

Comment: @PerDigesen thanks

Comment: @PerDigesen sorry for disturbing you again but i have tried a lot but new initiation does not work. I am using  io.connect('192.168.43.49:3000'); to connect to node server

Comment: try: `const newSocket = io('192.168.43.49:3000');` and then `newSocket.on('connection', (evt) => {..code})` etc.

Comment: @PerDigesen sorry but i can't use above suggestion because i have very large coding structure many socket.emit are used inside functions so it is not possible to remove those code from there to put inside newSocket.on('connction',(evt)=>{...code}). If i use this then i will be bounded to call socket.emit from inside 'connection' event

Comment: Try `io.open()` on the same socket that you disconnected

Comment: @PerDigesen sorry but does not work?

Comment: Try closing it and then in the disconnect event try opening it again: `socket.on('disconnect', function(evt) { socket.open(); })`

Comment: @PerDigesen not working

Comment: Then i suggest that you read about the client API for socket.io here: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/